# How to notice the user has disabled location services while the app is running in background?

Tags: ios, background, cllocationmanager, cllocation, location-services

I've enabled background mode for location services updates in my iOS app. I've seen that the `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` delegate method is called when the app goes to foreground, but I doesn't seem to be called while in background...

Thanks

**EDIT:** I'd want to know when the user has disabled location services in device's Settings being the app kept running in background... is that possible?

Comment: Yes, It will call in foreground. Its ios default behaviour.

Comment: The delegate only tells you what the user decided, and like Dharmbir said, its only in the foreground.

Are you wondering about how to receive location updates in the background? If so, I'd start here. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10

Comment: @feliun I do already listen for location updates in background, and I'd want to know when the user has disabled location services in device's Settings being the app kept running in background... is that possible?